# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null Error for while changing value of INNER HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Below is my JavaScript code. I want to display firstname + lastname instead of "Welcome user"(header text). I'm getting an error in the console saying that "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>This is Title</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function substitute(){
   var lastname=document.getElementById('lastname_id').value;
   var firstname=document.getElementById('firstname_id').value;
   console.log(lastname);
   console.log(firstname);
   if(lastname.length==0 || firstname.length==0){
     alert('Please enter values');
     return;
    }
   var myTitle=document.getElementById('user').value;
   console.log(myTitle);
   var myvalue = firstname+lastname;
   console.log(myvalue);
   myTitle.innerHTML = myvalue;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<h1 id="title">Welcome User</h1>
 First name:<br>
 <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname_id">
 <br>
 Last name:<br>
 <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname_id">
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit_id" onclick="substitute()">
 </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could append values directly to the tag 'h1' using 'innerText' :

```
document.getElementById('title').innerText = firstname+' '+lastname;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing an element with `id=user` but there is no element with `id=user`

```
document.getElementById('user').value;
```

You need to change the above line to

```
document.getElementById('title');
```

As you have an element `h1` with id `title`